# cabal install complains no acceptable C compiler found

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

When trying to install [snap](http://snapframework.com/) from cabal, in Windows, it complains about not being able to find a C compiler.

Here is the output:

```
> cabal update
> cabal install snap
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
directory-1.2.0.0 (new version)
clientsession-0.8.0.1 (new package)
directory-tree-0.10.1 (new version)
process-1.1.0.2 (new version)
heist-0.8.1.1 (reinstall) changes: directory-1.1.0.2 -> 1.2.0.0,
directory-tree-0.11.0 -> 0.10.1, process-1.1.0.1 -> 1.1.0.2
unix-compat-0.4.0.0 (new package)
configurator-0.2.0.1 (new package)
snap-core-0.9.2.1 (new package)
snap-server-0.9.2.3 (new package)
snap-0.9.2.1 (new package)
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Configuring directory-1.2.0.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/directory-1.2.0.0-4480/directory-1.2.0.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
clientsession-0.8.0.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
configurator-0.2.0.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
directory-1.2.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
directory-tree-0.10.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
heist-0.8.1.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
process-1.1.0.2 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
snap-0.9.2.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
snap-core-0.9.2.1 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
snap-server-0.9.2.3 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
unix-compat-0.4.0.0 depends on directory-1.2.0.0 which failed to install.
```

Why in the world does it need C compiler if it's written in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs a C compiler because the directory package has bits written in C (accessed via the FFI), as you can see from [the c-sources section of the cabal file](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/1.2.0.0/directory.cabal).

Comment: Interesting, somehow I recall compiling this a few months ago without c compiler... maybe I was drunk. Do you know if there are any haskell web-frameworks that don't require a C compiler?

Comment: @drozzy If your real question is how to compile this, then you need to modify your question. (Currently, the only sentence with a question mark is, "Why does it need a C compiler?".) But perhaps you will like the `--constraint "directory installed"` option to cabal-install.

Comment: No no, you answered it to my liking. I just can't accept it yet.. In fact I didn't know about `c-sources` section in cabal file - now I will check it myself! What does this constraint directive do?

Comment: @drozzy It asks cabal to try to find a collection of package versions that doesn't require reinstalling the `directory` package (which you almost certainly already have). See the cabal documentation for more information.

Comment: It's amazing, I think it worked! But why did you write "directory installed" and not simply "directory"?

Comment: the comment with the "--constraint" deserves the answer-reputation - maybe you can consider making that an anwer - I would gladly upvote it!